# How to populate a table view in a order based off an element from a class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, tableview

I have the following structures and arrays for my data and for my table view cells:

```
struct CellData
{
    var cell: Int! = 1
    var SegueIdentiier: String!
    var text: String!
    var image: UIImage!
}
struct Course {
    var isEmpty: Bool = true
    var Title: String = String()
    var FK: String = String()
    var Subject: String = String()
    var teacher_fk: String = String()
    var teacher_name: String = String()
    var grading_period: String = String()
    var room: String = String()
    var block_abbreviation: String = String()
    var block: Int = 0
    var parser: XMLParser!
}
var ArrayOfCellData = [CellData(), CellData(), CellData(), CellData(), CellData(), CellData(), CellData(), CellData()]
var Courses = [Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course(), Course()]
```

And when I parse an XML file the "block" is filled with a given number. Id like to populate my table view in order of these block numbers.
Ie if `Courses[0].block = 4 and Courses[3].block = 2` id like to populate my table view in the order of Courses[3] then Courses[0].

I cant figure out how to do this for the life of me. This is my first time posting on Stackoverflow so please be nice! :)

Comment: The order it is displayed in your tableView will probably be the order of your `Courses` array (btw consider renaming it to `courses`) if you implement `cellForRow` method in the classic way. Just sort it in the way you want like this by example: `courses = courses.sorted({ $0.block < $1.block })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired behaviour would be to sort your list of courses according to your desired sorting criteria.

```
Courses.sort {
    $0.block < $1.block
}
```

You could also have a sorted copy of your list if the initial order is important for some reasons.

Comment: Wow this is way simpler than what I found in the documentation. I need to dive deeper into Swift.

Comment: This is the functional way to do it, as far as I know. You could do something similar with filter, reduce, map, etc.

Comment: I found the sortedArray method on NSArrays in the documentation, but it was far more convoluted than this, and required a separate function returning NSOrdered values. This is just far simpler and cleaner. Not to mention their discussion example was only in Obj-C, so I had to convert to Swift which I'm not firm with. I'm surprised by how lacking of examples Apple's documentation can be sometimes.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated. Ill attempt to bootstrap your wizard code to my novice code.

Comment: You just need to call this method in viewDidLoad / anywhere you update your data source array, then call `tableView.reloadData()` to make sure the table is up to date.

Comment: @JakeT. The doc is getting better everyday. You can get some interesting closures like the sort shortand version at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 0):

Edit - The other answer appears way simpler than mine, I'd totally go with that one haha.  Though here is an example of looking up the documentation and working with what it tells you!

You need to sort your arrays. The indexPath of your cells needs to be able to uniquely determine the index of your array for your data to generate the cell, so you want your array to be sorted before you load the table.

You'll need to write a custom sort function for this, but it should be very easy: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1408213-sortedarray

Your sort should look something like this:

```
func intSort(course1:Course, course2:Course, void *context) -> NSInteger
{
    int v1 = course1.block;
    int v2 = course2.block;
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

You may ned to pass the courses as Any and cast them to Courses in the function, but this should get you started.

Comment: Your answers are like my children, I love you both equally even if one of you is more successful. I appreciate your help immensely, Bob.